# Parsing Confilict multiple if else and logical operation text in Android

Tags: java, android, split, hashtable

Simple but I could not understand part.

I have String **logictext1="IF (QN_723_0 >= 25 AND QN_723_0 <= 30) THEN QN_723_1 = 75 END IF";**

let us assume `QN_723_0 is Age` and `QN_723_1 is weight`.

You see above my string , it is clear also.

```
if I gave input age 28 and weight exactly 75 then return true output otherwise false..

if I gave input age 45 and weight exactly 75 then gives false output.

if I gave input age 45 and weight exactly 74 then gives true output.
```

How can I do it?  My main problem is how to parsing above if else and then string in java.

[image]

Comment: Excetly means this weight is fix 75,75,74 etx..not <75 and <75 right?

Comment: Actually i have previous string this `QN_770_0=QN_770_0\10`, splitting successfully but i am confused how to splitting above string.

Comment: @dipali , yest weight is fix. if 75 gave input in weight edittext field, check the previous age group condition. if match true otherwise false return.

Comment: age group condition `QN_723_0 >= 25 AND QN_723_0 <= 30` if true.

Comment: @dipali First of all he is not able to explain his answer. dont comment which are not constructive.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean GetValue() {
    int QN_723_0_age = 0, QN_723_1_weight = 0;
    if ((QN_723_0_age >= 25 && QN_723_0_age <= 30)) {
                QN_723_1_weight == 75;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I hope its useful to you....

```
if i gave input age 28 and weight exactly 75 then return true output 

if i gave input age 45 and weight exactly 75 then gives false output.

if i gave input age 45 and weight exactly 74 then gives false output.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am unable to splitting above logic string.`IF (QN_723_0 >= 25 AND QN_723_0 <= 30) THEN QN_723_1 = 75 END IF";`

Comment: The output of this doesn't depend on the weight at all; it doesn't meet standard coding conventions; and it's not a correct answer to the question.